# Can you attack twice in one turn?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons-board-game

I'm talking about *Dungeons & Dragons: The Fantasy Adventure Board Game* published in 2002 by Parker Brothers, a division of Hasbro.

In the *"Actions*" part of the rulebook it says:

> Each Hero may take 2 Actions on each turn. You can choose to take 1 or no Actions if you wish.
>
> The following Actions are all possible within the game and use 1 Action each:
> [...]

It doesn't specify whether you can choose the same action twice in the same turn or not but in a later example (only in the *Dungeon Master's Guide (pg. 8)*) it says (explicitly for Monsters):

> [...]
> You can decide not to move or attack with a Monster or not to attack and take a double move. [...]

I am pretty sure, that they want to say that Monsters can't attack twice, but I am not so sure about player characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that player characters **are** capable of attacking twice. The rules state you have 2 Actions to spend each turn, spent on a list of actions that cost 1 Action each, with no further limitations beyond the cost.

This is reinforced when they explicitly state that this option is not available to Monsters, a case of "the exception proves the rule".

I.e., "no free parking on Sundays" implies parking is free every other day. Monsters can't attack twice (without stating otherwise for players) implies Player Characters can.

Comment: Yeah, this is the clear interpretation. The game says "you can take two actions" and "each time you take an action it can be one of these". Unless it explicitly says otherwise, this clearly allows taking the same action twice.